# How to pass JavaScript variables to Django template tags and filters?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, templatetags

I could pass `Hello` to [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag's `dj_val` and [upper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#upper) filter in `<script></script>` in `index.html`, then `Hello` and `HELLO` was displayed on console as shown below:

```
{% "index.html" %}

<script>
{% with dj_val="Hello" %}
    console.log("{{ dj_val }}") # Hello
{% endwith %}

console.log("{{ "Hello"|upper }}") # HELLO
</script>
```

But, I could not pass JavaScript's `js_val` set `Hello` to `with` tag's `dj_val` and `upper` filter in `<script></script>` in `index.html`, then nothing was displayed on console as shown below:

```
{% "index.html" %}

<script>
let js_val = "Hello"

{% with dj_val=js_val %}
    console.log("{{ dj_val }}") # Nothing
{% endwith %}

console.log("{{ js_val|upper }}") # Nothing
</script>
```

So, how can I pass JavaScript's `js_val` set `Hello` to `with` tag's `dj_val` and `upper` filter to display `Hello` and `HELLO` on console?

Comment: You cannot access js_val in Python, because js_val is a Javascript variable.

Comment: https://adamj.eu/tech/2022/10/06/how-to-safely-pass-data-to-javascript-in-a-django-template/